# How do you calculate field strength and velocity of the field needed to create an electrical current in a material?

Tags: electromagnetism

Like for instance, say I have a piece of glass. I'm sure there's some equation and series of coefficients I need to answer this question, but I got no idea what they are. How do you calculate how strong of a magnet you need going at a given speed to make electricity from a given material?

Comment: We need more details about the situation. Do you just want eddy currents in a bulk piece of glass? Is the glass a hoop or some sort of wire for carrying current? What has velocity in this setup? How much current do you want? Why glass, which is an electrical insulator? This is not an exhaustive list of questions.

Comment: Okay, well there's no exhaustive list of possible situations either...I have no idea what eddy currents would be relevant to and I'm looking for a more generalized equation.

Comment: The generalized equations would be Maxwell's equations, but I don't think those will help you much. The answer to your question depends entirely on what you want to happen. Moving a magnet at any speed near any material generates some amount of electric current, even if immeasurable.